# addTab jquery IE10 notworking

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a simple webpage that allows users to create new tabs.

Using IE9, everything works fine.  Using IE10, you can add a new tab, but when you click on it, the others containers get white and you lose the content.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you show us the code, or at least make an example that we can use to demonstate the issue (like on http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: If I add a new tab, that inside has an Iframe that has a frame, then I got the error. White content.

Comment: Hello Again:

This is the final example of my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/pUVmV/5/)


As you can see, if you add a new frame, appears the text. If you change tab, you loose both texts....

The content of the tabs is a simple page:

Comment: Here is the content of the new tab container: <frameset border="0" >
<frame name="base" id="base" HSCROLLING="no" src="hello.php"  hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
</frameset>
</HTML>

Comment: My example Works fine if you modify src of iframes with any external link (without frames).

Comment: In IE10, all pages as part of a `<frameset>` need to be in the same "document type".  http://www.ravenglass.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/5/17/IE10s-compatibility-mode-and-framesets

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I've migrated all my App to IFRAME. I've seen that frameset and frame are not longer supported by IE10. Has been a hard job but I think that is the best way. Thanks a lot, anyway. I'll keep in mind your help.

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad I could help! :-D